# Can I use oracle_enhanced adapter in vanity gem for AB Testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, ab-testing, vanity

For my production database, I am using oracle_enhanced adapter. Is this supported by vanity gem?
From https://github.com/assaf/vanity, it says: "Vanity supports multiple SQL stores (like MySQL, MariaDB, Postgres, Sqlite, etc.) using ActiveRecord, which is built into Rails".
I am not sure if this etc includes Oracle.

I tried using the below in my config/vanity.yml:

```
production:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: mydb.XXX.com
  username: XXX
  password: XXX
  port: XXXX
  database: mydb
```

But what I get is the error message below:

```
Could not find oracle_enhanced in your load path (RuntimeError)
```

My config/database.yml is actually using `adapter: oracle_enhanced`.

Any advice what I'm missing?

[UPDATED]
Below is the stack trace:

```
Could not find oracle_enhanced in your load path (RuntimeError)
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/adapters.rb:16:in `rescue in establish_connection'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/adapters.rb:13:in `establish_connection'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/connection.rb:95:in `establish_connection'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/connection.rb:68:in `setup_connection'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/connection.rb:36:in `initialize'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/vanity.rb:98:in `new'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/vanity.rb:98:in `connect!'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/vanity.rb:69:in `connection'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/frameworks/rails.rb:12:in `block in load!'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /home/si/si_trunk/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /home/si/si_trunk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/httpd/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:105:in `eval'
  /usr/local/httpd/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:105:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/httpd/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:150:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/httpd/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/httpd/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Then I edited the config/vanity.yml to:

```
production:
  adapter: active_record
  active_record_adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: mydb.XXX.com
  database: mydb
  port: XXXX
  username: XXX
  password: XXX
```

This is the stack trace after updating the vanity.yml:

```
NameError ("DESC vanity_experiments" failed; does it exist?):
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_connection.rb:76:in `describe'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:219:in `rescue in describe'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:214:in `describe'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:1074:in `columns_without_cache'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:1063:in `columns'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:229:in `yield'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:229:in `columns'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:249:in `column_names'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:262:in `column_methods_hash'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:74:in `all_attributes_exists?'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:27:in `method_missing'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/adapters/active_record_adapter.rb:180:in `set_experiment_created_at'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/experiment/base.rb:159:in `save'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/experiment/ab_test.rb:544:in `save'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/experiment/definition.rb:21:in `define'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/experiment/ab_test.rb:708:in `ab_test'
  /experiments/price_options.rb:1:in `new_binding'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/experiment/base.rb:24:in `eval'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/experiment/base.rb:24:in `block in load'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/experiment/base.rb:22:in `instance_eval'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/experiment/base.rb:22:in `load'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/playground.rb:248:in `block in set_experiments'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/playground.rb:247:in `each'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/playground.rb:247:in `set_experiments'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/playground.rb:26:in `initialize'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/vanity.rb:137:in `new'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/vanity.rb:137:in `load!'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/vanity.rb:127:in `playground'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/templates.rb:25:in `custom_template_path_valid?'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/templates.rb:15:in `determine_template_directory'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/templates.rb:4:in `initialize'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/templates.rb:37:in `new'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/templates.rb:37:in `template'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/frameworks/rails.rb:365:in `index'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:558:in `block in _run__1055270493__process_action__1054591083__callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in _conditional_callback_around_1772'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vanity-2.2.1/lib/vanity/frameworks/rails.rb:146:in `vanity_context_filter'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:214:in `_conditional_callback_around_1772'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__1055270493__process_action__1054591083__callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:362:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:25:in `process_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:in `traced_call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-attack-3.0.0/lib/rack/attack.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__665799391__call__857586578__callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.6.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:140:in `forward'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.6.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:249:in `fetch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.6.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:189:in `lookup'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.6.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.6.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  /usr/local/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
  /usr/local/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:140:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/local/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
  /usr/local/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

Is this because the username in the config is not the owner of the table? But, actually, I already granted access (select, insert, update, delete) to the username in the config.

This is my VANITY_EXPERMINETS_TABLE:

```
COLUMN_NAME      DATA_TYPE          NULLABLE
EXPERIMENT_ID    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)  NO
OUTCOME          NUMBER(11,0)       YES
ENABLED          CHAR(1 BYTE)       YES
CREATED_AT       DATE               YES
COMPLETED_AT     DATE               YES
```

Comment: You might need to add this gem to your `Gemfile`: https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced

Comment: This gem is already in my Gemfile. I am using activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - Vanity will work with ActiveRecord database adapters.

As @ksarunas points out, you'll need to add the adapter to your gemfile and make sure that it's `require`d appropriately.

Also, make sure to use the connection setup described in the [README](https://github.com/assaf/vanity#sql-database-setup), paraphrased for this adapter:

```
# config/vanity.yml
development:
  adapter: active_record
  active_record_adapter: oracle_enhanced
  # database: ...
  # host: ...
test:
  adapter: active_record
  active_record_adapter: default # Can also use the default AR connection, no need to respecify all of the connection params
  collecting: false
production:
  adapter: active_record
  active_record_adapter: default
```

Also make sure to run the migrations to create the tables:

```
$ rails generate vanity
$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Hi, this gem is already in my Gemfile as this is the current adapter that I am using. I am using activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.3).

Comment: @Catherine can you post the stack trace of the error you're seeing?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the stack trace

Comment: @Catherine added notes on the config file and running the migrations.

Comment: I did not run the migrations. I added the tables manually. Added the table attributes on the question